# How can I use a function as a class attribute with EclipseLink?

Tags: java, function, lambda, eclipselink

Sorry if the title isn't very explicit, I don't really know how to make it clearer.

Basically, I would like to make a Java class, for which one of the attributes is a function, and I would like to persist instances of this class in a database, with EclipseLink (actually, this class would be a "Rule" that would compute some school marks, depending on criteria that would be given as parameters of the function).

I tried to use lambda expressions, it worked great until I tried to persist objects of this class, which didn't work. Here's the kind of errors that I got:

```
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2016-06-07 16:43:19.288--ServerSession(640363654)--java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [EvalComp_PUnit] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Here's the code that I used:

```
public interface Calcul
{
    public abstract Double calcul(Object arg);
}
```

Also:

```
@Entity
public class Regle implements Serializable
{
    //---------------------------- Attributs -----------------------------------

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String libelle;

    private Calcul formule;
}
```

(I didn't put the getters ans setters, I don't think they're useful here).

Then, the method I use to persist the class:

```
public Regle creerRegle(String libelle, Calcul calcul) throws Throwable
    {
        Regle r = new Regle(libelle, calcul);

        Regle test = trouverRegleParLibelle(libelle);

        if (test == null)
        {
            try
            {
                JpaUtil.creerEntityManager();

                RegleDao dao = new RegleDao();

                JpaUtil.ouvrirTransaction();

                dao.create(r);

                JpaUtil.validerTransaction();

                JpaUtil.fermerEntityManager();

                return r;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
```

(It basically creates an EntityManager, starts a transaction, persists the object, commits, and closes the transaction. This is done in all the functions inside this code, and I don't think the problem comes from here.)

Finally, in the main class:

```
Calcul test = (Object l) ->
{
    List<Boolean> li = (List<Boolean>) l;

    Double res = 20.;

    for (Boolean b : li)
    {
        if (res == 0.)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (!b)
        {
            res--;
        }
    }

    return res;
};

r = servM.creerRegle(libelle, test);
```

Do you know what I can do to solve this problem?

Thanks,

LeChocDesGitans.

Comment: JPA does allow storing serializable objects, just make your class hierarchy extend/implement the serializable interface, but as this is business logic, I'm not sure the point really.  Why are you trying to persist your formula into the database, and what does that mean exactly?  Won't the same formula be used for most classes - this seems business logic, not database data.  You might want to keep the formula itself in the application, and persist an enum or some such that tells you which forumla to use.

Comment: Actually, there might be a lot of different formulas eventually, since the users of the application I am developing will be able to create their own ones. That's why I would like to store them in the database.
I have already tried to make all my classes implement the Serializable interface, but it didn't work with the formulas I'm trying to persist.
But I'm going to try it again, with a different approach, thanks for your advice.

Comment: I finally found a very easy way to make this work, I just had to make my "Calcul" interface extend Serializable, now it can be persisted in the database. Thanks again for your advice!